# Why is there a big gap in the actual Table space? (calculated vs information_schema vs file size)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, centos, mariadb-10.5

I have a InnoDB table with the following columns:

`BIGINT` -> 8 bytes
`BIGINT` -> 8 bytes
`ENUM(0,1)` -> 1 byte
`MEDIUMINT` -> 3 bytes
`INT` -> 4 bytes

= 24 bytes per row

It contains 10454004 rows (based on `COUNT(*)`), so I calculate the Data size as **250MB**.

This table's `PRIMARY` key is `BIGINT`, `BIGINT`, `ENUM`.
And has an `INDEX` on the `INT`.

Based on `information_schema`,
`DATA_LENGTH` = **530.8MiB**
`INDEX_LENGTH` = 272.0MiB
`DATA_FREE` = 6.0MiB
= 808.8MiB = **848 MB**

Also, `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` = 87 instead of 24

And then I look at the actual `.ibd` file size, which is reported as:
1451229184 bytes = **1451.23 MB**

I understand there is fragmentation and sparse files in question (the records on this table are regularly expired, but never had a bigger retention time than currently is).
But I'm not understanding why do I see 3 different sizes, with such big gap each.

Goes from 250MB of real calculable data, to 530MiB of Data.
And `DATA_FREE` is only 6MiB.

And 848 MB reported by `information_schema` (which per my understanding includes "free space" as well), much lower than the actual `.ibd` file.

**From Comment**

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `uid` bigint(18) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `tid` bigint(18) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `fst` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    `sn` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
    `ls` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`tid`,`fst`) USING BTREE, 
    KEY `ls` (`ls`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**What am I missing or not considering?**

Comment: OPTIMIZE TABLE may claim and cut off some unused space (I hope that your table uses InnoDB with innodb_file_per_table set).

Comment: Hi. Thanks - I suspected that the fragmentation could have been caused by the frequent DELETEs. But in the other hand, shouldn't the "free space" be re-used by new INSERTs? Or is it not that simple? (as the primary key must be organized sequentially, etc?), otherwise it kind of defeats the purpose of "expiring data", if space isn't reclaimed. (btw, yes, I have Barracuda and `innodb_file_per_table=1`)

Comment: I'm aware of `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, but unfortunately that locks the table in many scenarios, but even if it doesn't, at the end of the process it seems to lock for a few seconds anyway. So my experience with it hasn't been the best. Both MySQL and MariaDB have been doing a great job over the years by making online DDL processes much better, so I'm hoping OPTIMIZE TABLE will eventually be 100% lock-free! :)

Comment: *shouldn't the "free space" be re-used by new INSERTs?* It should... if the insert must be performed into this close-to-empty block. *as the primary key must be organized sequentially* PK is clustered index in InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB has a lot of overhead.

- NULL/NOT NULL
- length for VARCHAR  (N/A in your example)
- 20-30 bytes overhead for each row -- including transaction-related things
- fragmentation because of BTree blocking.  On average, a block is only 69% full due to the way rows are inserted/deleted without any big reorganization.
- A simple Rule of Thumb:  As a Rule of Thumb, the table will take 2x-3x the space you would predict from BIGINT=8 bytes, etc.
- SHOW TABLE STATUS is notoriously imprecise.  The Data_length is precise (and a multiple of 16KB) and the product of Avg_row_length and Row_size is, within rounding errors, equal to Data_length.  But those two are only approximate.
- Data_free usually shows a multiple of 1MB between 4MB and 7MB.  This is due to its preallocating large chunks.
- Tables that *were* created with `innodb_file_per_table=ON` are in their own `.ibd` file.  The others are sharing spacing in the file `ibdata1`.  The `Data_free` for the former is tied to the table; for the latter, it is for the entire tablespace.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` (an index) is included (clustered) with the data.  Hence it takes virtually no disk space.  (Rule of Thumb: about 1% overhead.)
- Each secondary key includes a copy of the PK  -- in your example, the `KEY(ls)` will be nearly as big as the table.
- When talking about a table schema, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there are several details you left out.
- And the example does not include a `TEXT`/`BLOB` that might be stored "off-record".
- And the example does get into what happens with different charsets/collations.

Comment: Thank you very much Rick. I think most of what was said above I am already aware of. I think it still doesn't fully explain why the big gaps though! Here's the ```CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`uid` bigint(18) unsigned NOT NULL, `tid` bigint(18) unsigned NOT NULL, `fst` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `sn` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, `ls` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`tid`,`fst`) USING BTREE, KEY `ls` (`ls`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci```

Comment: @Nuno - I added the CREATE to your Question (so others can see, too).  I made a few tweaks in my answer, but not surprises.  Perhaps another example might provide more insight.